# Two-parameter “$\varepsilon$-$\delta$ filtration” given a function between metric spaces

Tags: reference-request, computational-topology, persistent-homology

Let $X,Y$ be metric space and $f : X \to Y$ a (not necessarily continuous) function. I'm interested in the two-parameter filtration $(X_{\varepsilon, \delta})_{{\varepsilon, \delta} > 0}$ where $X_{{\varepsilon, \delta}}$ is the clique complex of the graph $(X,V)$ such that that $\left\{x,y\right\} \in V$ iff $d(f(x), f(y)) < \varepsilon$ and $d(x,y) < \delta$.

The motivation is the following: if $X = [m] \times [n]$ is a discrete grid of pixels and $Y = [0,1]$, so that $f$ represents a greyscale image, then the persistent homology of $X_{\bullet\ \bullet}$ computes a topological segmentation of the image that is robust against gradients and shading.

[image: Greyscale sphere]

I would be grateful for any references to previous work on this idea or other ideas in the same vein.

Many thanks.